# ssh-keygen: The System Cannot Find the Path Specified

Tags: powershell, ssh, posh-git, ssh-keygen

- ssh-agent, ssh-add all works on Cmder running PowerShell/Posh-Git
- I have added `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin` Environment Variables
- `ssh-keyen` works fine on Git Bash,
- how can I make ssh-keygen to also work with ***Powershell/Posh-Git ?***

**EDIT:**

It turns out that the error is due to the fact that ssh-keygen in PowerShell is running the `ssh-keygen.bat` file instead of `ssh-keygen.exe`

So setting an alias as mention below is the way to go.

I use `Set-Alias` instead of `New-Alias` because `New-Alias` requires me to reset my $profile every now and then, which is weird.

To reset, type `. $profile`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do this is to add it to your path.

Unfortunately, there appears to be no way to add **only** the executable. In other words, you will be required to add the whole `bin` folder (namely `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin`) to your path.

I can show you how to add the whole directory to the path, but I don't think this is what you want. Instead, below is an alternative method that **only** adds the `ssh-keygen.exe` executable.

1. Navigate to `$env:homepath\Documents\WindowsPowerShell` (create it if you don't have it).
2. Create a file called `profile.ps1`.
3. Add to the file the following line of code.
   `New-Alias Ssh-Keygen "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\ssh-keygen.exe"`

Now, each time you launch Powershell, `Ssh-Keygen` will be available. It even works with tab completion (e.g. type `ssh-` and press tab, then it automatically becomes `Ssh-Keygen`).

Comment: Actually, you can add single executables from the git bin folder to your path. I also posted an answer. I thought it might also be of interest to you, so I'm commenting to have you notified ;)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can **add single executables from the git bin folder to your path** by symlinking them into a folder that is contained in your path variable.
I also wanted to use some of the git tools inside powershell but I didn't want to load the git-bin-folder into path every time I wanted to use one of the tools and I also didn't want to overwrite tools like `cp`, `find`, `ls` and so on...

- Create a folder that you can add to path. I created mine in `C:\dev\bin` and added it to the path variable.
- Then you need to symlink all the dll-files from the git bin folder to your new bin folder because the tools you'll link need them in the same directory (the runpath won't be the git-bin-dir but the new bin-dir). I'll add a Script to do that below.
- And finally you just need to create symlinks for all tools you'd like to use in powershell as well (hint: ssh.exe is really nice to use in powershell ;))

Here are my powershell functions that'll help you set up your new bin-folder with all the nice tools from git:

```
# generic symlink function
function Create-Symlink {
    param(
        [string]$link,
        [string]$target
    )

    & cmd.exe /c mklink "$link" "$target"
}

# symlink all teh git dlls
function Create-GitDllSymlinks {
    param(
        [string]$newBinDir='C:\dev\bin',
        [string]$gitBinDir='C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin'
    )

    $dlls = gci $gitBinDir -Filter *.dll

    $dlls | foreach {
        Create-Symlink -link (join-path $newBinDir $_.Name) -target $_.FullName
    }
}

# to easily link your git tools
function Create-GitSymlink {
    param(
        [string]$executable,
        [string]$newBinDir='C:\dev\bin',
        [string]$gitBinDir='C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin'
    )

    if (-not $executable.EndsWith('.exe')) {
        $executable = ($executable + '.exe')
    }

    Create-Symlink -link (join-path $newBinDir $executable) -target (join-path $gitBinDir $executable)
}

# create all dll symlinks needed
Create-GitDllSymlinks
# link ssh and ssh-keygen to use in powershell
Create-GitSymlink -executable ssh-keygen
Create-GitSymlink -executable ssh
```

Another nice thing to do is this:

- create a bash.bat file in your new bin-folder
- write this into that .bat file:

  `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i`
- quickly switch between powershell and bash:

  - when in powershell, type `bash` and git-bash will start inside the same window with access to all git tools in the git-bin-folder.
  - want to go back to powershell? just type exit!

**Edit:**
I reinstalled my computer a few days ago (with Win 10) and ran into some issues with my solution above. Apparently, git and/or the cygwin environment in git has been updated and the cygwin applications now search for their unix-environment-paths differently.

For example, `ssh` always said that it couldn't find my home path:

```
Could not create directory '/home/myuser/.ssh'.
The authenticity of host 'hostx (IP)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:xxxxxx.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

Using `procmon` I found out, that it was looking for files in `c:\etc` and `c:\home\myuser`. Setting environment variables like HOME or USERPROFILE didn't work, so I just made two additional symlinks to satisfy my cygwin tools:

```
PS bin # cmd /c mklink /D C:\etc "C:\Program Files\Git\etc"
symbolic link created for C:\etc <<===>> C:\Program Files\Git\etc
PS bin # cmd /c mklink /D C:\home "C:\Users"
symbolic link created for C:\home <<===>> C:\Users
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by generating my own ssh key pair using command

$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your_email@mail.com"

in powershell. If you already have a SSH key, then don't a generate new key, as they will be overwritten. You can use ssh-keygen command, only if you have installed Git with Git Bash.

When you run the above command, it will create 2 files in the ~/.ssh directory.

~/.ssh/id_rsa − It is private key or identification key.

~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub − public key

See link [generate ssh key](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/gerrit/gerrit_generate_new_ssh_key.htm)